# How to change a variable value in a python parent class from sub class method just for class instance

Tags: python, class, subclass

ok, I am not even entirely sure if my title is completely accurate as I completely do not understand class inheritance and instances at that moment but understand it is something that I need or should grasp moving forward.

Background:  attempting to create a custom importer for my bank to be used with the popular Beancount/fava double entry ledger accounting system.  I originally reported to fava as a bug but then realized its not a bug and its more my lack of general understanding of Python classes so thought it would be better to post here.

So...I have created the following import script file which as I understand is a sub class of beancount csv.Importer (https://github.com/beancount/beancount/blob/master/beancount/ingest/importers/csv.py) which is a sub class of beancount Importer (https://github.com/beancount/beancount/blob/master/beancount/ingest/importer.py)

In my importer I over ride 2 methods of csv.Importer, name() and file_account().  My goal is to derive the source account associated to input file based on file name and dictionary look-up.  The extract() method I do not wish to over-ride in my sub class, however in the csv.Importer extract() method there is reference to self.account that represents the source account to use for extracted transactions.  Currently the way my script is if I feed it a file named 'SIMPLII_9999_2018-01-01.csv' the account will be properly derived as 'Assets:Simplii:Chequing-9999'.  However, if I stop short of actually importing the transactions in fava and instead attempt to extract the transactions again from the same file the derived account then becomes 'Assets:Simplii:Chequing-9999 **:Chequing-9999**'.

What I am trying to do is derive the source account from the input file and pass this information as the self.account variable in the parent class (csv.Importer) for my class instance (I think).  What is it that I am doing wrong in my class that is causing the derived source account to be carried over to the next instance?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from beancount.ingest import extract
from beancount.ingest.importers import csv
from beancount.ingest import cache
from beancount.ingest import regression
import re
from os import path

from smart_importer.predict_postings import PredictPostings

class SimpliiImporter(csv.Importer):
    '''
    Importer for the Simplii bank.
    Note: This undecorated class can be regression-tested with
    beancount.ingest.regression.compare_sample_files
    '''

    config = {csv.Col.DATE: 'Date',
            csv.Col.PAYEE: 'Transaction Details',
            csv.Col.AMOUNT_DEBIT: 'Funds Out',
            csv.Col.AMOUNT_CREDIT: 'Funds In'}

    account_map = {'9999':'Chequing-9999'}

    def __init__(self, *, account, account_map=account_map):
      self.account_map = account_map
      self.account = 'Assets:Simplii'

      super().__init__(
        self.config,
        self.account,
        'CAD',
        ['Filename: .*SIMPLII_\d{4}_.*\.csv',
         'Contents:\n.*Date, Transaction Details, Funds Out, Funds In'],
        institution='Simplii'
        )

    def name(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        return '{}.{}'.format(cls.__module__, cls.__name__)

    def file_account(self, file):
        __account = None
        if file:
            m = re.match(r'.+SIMPLII_(\d{4})_.*', file.name)[1]
            if m:
                sub_account = self.account_map.get(m)
                if sub_account:
                    __account = self.account + ':' + sub_account
        return __account

    def extract(self, file):
        self.account = self.file_account(file)
        return super().extract(file)


@PredictPostings(training_data='/beancount/personal.beancount')
class SmartSimpliiImporter(SimpliiImporter):
    '''
    A smart version of the Simplii importer.
    '''
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

so I have managed to get this working however I don't think its the proper way to do it...

I changed the extract function like this

```
def extract(self, file):
    self.account = self.file_account(file)
    postings = super().extract(file)
    self.account = 'Assets:Simplii'
    return postings
```

basically I set the self.account to the value I need to, call the parent class extract function saving results to variable, reset the self.account variable and return results.  Seems more of a work around than the proper way but at least its here in case it helps someone else out...